# Aggregating list of a specific field in different "columns" using mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation

Using mongo-driver on Golang.

In order to save a list of relations between 2 entities I'm using a collection where each document has an "uid1" and an "uid2", which are unique identifiers for each entity. Any entity can be on both sides. The objective is to find all the entities that have a relation with the one I select and put it into a list. Currently by doing:

```
cursor, err := RelationsColl.Find(ctx, bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{bson.M{"uid1": UID}, bson.M{"uid2": UID}}})

    var res []bson.M
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &res); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

I get in variable `res` a list of entries where the `UID` variable is present. What I want to get instead, is simply a list with the UIDs in the correspondent entry. So instead of getting something in the form of: (imagine we request entities with a relation with "xxxx")

```
[[uid1:xxxx uid2:yyyy],[uid1:zzzz uid2:xxxx]]
```

I can get something in the form of:

```
[yyyy, zzzz]
```

Is this possible to do with aggregations?

Hope I was clear, if there is anything not explicitly explained please comment below.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your data is like this `{uid1: "xxxx", uid2: "yyyy"}, {uid1: "zzzz", uid2: "xxxx"}`. The output you want for filter `xxxx` is `["yyyy", "zzzz"]` using MongoDB Aggregation. Correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: exactly, I do not need it to be aggregation. I just thought it would be the correct way to do it. I'm fine with using other mongodb solution. My current solution is just taking it out as it is and then going through the elements and extracting the values I want in a cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should do the trick for you

```
UID := "id-1"  // Change this variable to your `match` value

matchStage := bson.D{
    {"$match", bson.D{
        {"$or", bson.A{
            bson.D{{"uid1", UID}},
            bson.D{{"uid2", UID}},
        }},
    }},
}
groupStage := bson.D{
    {"$group", bson.D{
        {"_id", nil},
        {"uids1", bson.D{
            {"$addToSet", "$uid1"},
        }},
        {"uids2", bson.D{
            {"$addToSet", "$uid2"},
        }},
    }},
}
projectStage := bson.D{
    {"$project", bson.D{
        {"uids", bson.D{
            {"$filter", bson.D{
                {"input", bson.D{
                    {"$concatArrays", bson.A{"$uids1", "$uids2"}},
                }},
                {"as", "arrayElem"},
                {"cond", bson.D{
                    {"$ne", bson.A{"$$arrayElem", UID}},
                }},
            }},
        }},
    }},
}
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(
    ctx,
    mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, groupStage, projectStage},
    options.Aggregate().SetAllowDiskUse(true),
    )
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var cursorResult []bson.M
err = cursor.All(ctx, &cursorResult)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("Cursor Result: ", cursorResult[0]["uids"])
```